# How can I change the location which Anki uses to save files?

Tags: uti

The program Anki saves its data to the Documents folder. I would like to move this folder to my Dropbox folder. Anki has no settings which allows you to change the location that data is stored.

Is there any way to move this folder to another location and point Anki to the new folder via Mac OS X? I tried moving the folder and then creating an Alias in the same location (with the same name) by <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd> dragging the file in Finder, but Anki doesn't see the files in the new folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may be able to use Symbolic Links to create a link between where Anki stores its files and a folder within DropBox.  Information on how to create symbolic links and how they differ from Aliases can be found here:

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2001110610290643

Comment: It worked out best when I did a symbolic link between my dropbox folder/anki/decks folder and ~/Documents/Anki
Afterward had to explicitly open all decks with Anki to register. Now they all sync with dropbox. Haven't tried with a mobile device.

Answer (score 2):

When going to documents folder there is a readme with [link](http://ankisrs.net/docs/manual.html#startupopts) to the user manual. That page has several ways to pick the data location. Portable mode is my pick.  Standalone also looks good.

Adding the `-b` flag was not working until I read

`On Windows, right-click on the shortcut, choose Properties, select the Shortcut tab, and add "-b \path\to\data\folder" after the path to the program…`

which should leave you with something like

`C:\Program Files\Anki\anki.exe" -b "C:\AnkiDataFolder"`

There are options for Macintosh and flash drive too, all on that same page.

Answer (score 1):

As of Anki 2.1, the `ANKI_BASE` environment variable should be work per [this](https://github.com/dae/anki/pull/58#issuecomment-285900005). However, you might need to set it in a Launch Daemon / Agent for Anki to figure it out if you use Spotlight. Tested `2.1.0beta4`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that is not the best way. You can run Anki in portable mode and specify the path to a different data folder. Create a shortcut to Anki.exe and change the target path to this:

```
anki.exe -b "D:\Anki"
```

Close Anki, move your Anki data files to D:\Anki (or whatever folder you choose) and restart Anki.

Comment: Mac does not use drive letters, nor executable files with .exe file extensions.